# (Django, South) New models aren't added to panel admin after migration, "Permission denied"

Tags: django, django-admin, django-south

I have recently added new models to site using South, but after migration new models aren't shown in admin panel (they are registered in admin.py).

I have also changed old models fields to link to new models (by foreignkey or manytomanyfield), but when I want to add new model (by a pop-up window being in a window of an old model) using this green plus sign, pop-up window is shown, but it has only "permission denied" text. There are no any fields of a new model.

Could you help me? Maybe I have overlooked something...

Comment: Did you maybe add the new models inside a new app and didn't add that app to INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Nope, new models were added to old app...

Comment: Does your user have the required permissions? Are you doing this as superuser?

Comment: Hey, yes, i figured this and this was the problem. I change permissions as superuser and now everything works fine.